# React-native : Maintaining state of multiple filter buttons / multiple filters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have been trying to achieve a functionality for filtering the data.

Here is [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-filter-button-state-3lqyi) with boiler plate sample.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Multiple selection is allowed.
I am not too sure how to approach this implementation.

Since we are maintaining multiple buttons state, I am thinking of maintaining some kind of array or dictionary with details of tag name and its current status (selected or  not selected)

but I am not track sure how to track each toggle status, which item was selected and which was unselected.

Some guidance will be helpful.

Comment: `isSeleceted` should start a an empty array and you should be checking if the index of the item is in the array or not - depending on that you filter it out, or add it to the array

Comment: How to maintain state of each button if it was selected or not?

Answer (score 0):

since you are dealing with an array of buttons, your `isSelected` should be an array. so what you do is add the index of the clicked item into the array. if the index is in the array, it means that item is selected. but, since you want to disable buttons as well, you need to check if the index is in the array already, if it is, you need to remove it. if it the array doesn't contain the index, then you add the index into the array.

the only changes I did to your code is :

1.change the handleFilterPress

```
function handleFilterPress(tag, index) {
    // check if the array contains the index
  if (isSelected.includes(index)) {
   //  if yes, filter it out of the array
    setIsSelected((prevItems) => prevItems.filter((el) => el !== index));
   // otherwise, add it to the array
  } else setIsSelected((prevItems) => [...prevItems, index]);
}
```

now the only thing that needs to change, is the way the item knows if it should be green or not.

right after the handleFilterPress function, declare a new function expression

```
const isButtonSelected = (index) => isSelected.includes(index);
```

this function checkes if the item is in the array and returns a boolean.
so then, in your ternary operator, you use that function to see if the button is in the array.

```
     style={[
        {
           backgroundColor: isButtonSelected(index)
             ? "green"
             : "rgba(26, 28, 44, 0.08)",
           borderRadius: 4,
           margin: 3,
           width: (deviceWidth - 40) / 3 - 20,
           alignItems: "center"
        }
      ]}
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could try your solution in sandbox link I provided. I tried but it didnt work so just wondering if I missed anything. Thanks